# Evaluate area of a surface

Tags: integration

The cylinder $x^2$ + $y^2$ = $x$ divdies the unit sphere S into two regions $S_1$ and $S_2$, where $S_1$ is inside the cylinder and $S_2$ outside. Find the ratio of areas $A(S_2)$/$A(S_1)$

I think the area $S_1$ and $S_2$ are not surface of a revolution, right?

So, I think I should parametrize it, but I can't. How can I do it? or am I wrong?

Comment: I think I should parametrize it using polar coordinates, find the appropriate limits of integration, and then integrate.

Comment: can you explain it more specifically?

Comment: Please have a first try and show some of the ideas you have in mind.